# Want to send image file using sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets

using a library called ImageGrab from PIL folder, i tryed to screenshot the server screen and send it to the customer. I saved the screenshot in a folder but how to send it? and if the image size is too big how do I split it and send it in pieces to the customer?

Server Side:

```
import socket
from PIL import ImageGrab

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind('0.0.0.0', 8820)
server_socket.listen(1)

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
print client_address + ' Have connected to server'
commend = client_socket.recv(1024)
while commend != 'exit':
    if commend == 'screenShot':
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
        im.save(r'C:\screen.jpg')


server_socket.close()
```

Client Side:

```
    import socket

my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 8820)

commend = raw_input('Connected! Enter your commend')
my_socket.send(commend)



my_socket.close()
```

ty for help

Comment: Do you need to use a socket or could you use a higher level protocol? Possibly use http server and GET a screenshot. Or we sockets https://www.fullstackpython.com/websockets.html

Comment: only sockets my friend...